# Pig Latin Translator won't give out a word

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I need to complete a working Pig Latin translator for a class. The translator is supposed to take a word and if it begins with a vowel add "ay" at the end and if it begins with a consonant take the consonant to the back and then add "ay" it should keep moving back until it hits a vowel. For example the word ¨tree¨ should become "eetray". I´m not sure where in the code I when wrong, but when I run the could it doesn't give me anything so if I put in "tree" it will just restart the code and ask for a word again. Any help would be welcome. Thanks!

```
vowels = "AEIOU" 
realLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
while true:
     isRealWord = True
 word = raw_input ("Please tell me a word to translate: ").lower()
 for letter in range(len(word)):
     if word[letter] in realLetters:
         continue
     else:
         print "That is not a real word. Just leave."
         isRealWord = False

 if isRealWord == True:
    firstLetter = word[0]
    secondLetter = word[1]
    thirdLetter = word[2]

    pigWord0 = word + "ay"

    TheRestOfTheWord = word[1:]
    pigWord1 = TheRestOfTheWord + firstLetter + "ay"

    TheRestOfTheWord = word[2:]
    pigWord2 = TheRestOfTheWord + firstLetter + secondLetter + "ay"

    TheRestOfTheWord = word[3:]
    pigWord3 = TheRestOfTheWord + firstLetter + secondLetter + thirdLetter + "ay"

    if pigWord0[0] in vowels:
        print pigWord0.lower()
    elif pigWord1[0] in vowels:
        print pigWord1.lower()
    elif pigWord2[0] in vowels:
        print pigWord2.lower()
    elif pigWord3[0] in vowels:
        print pigWord3.lower()
```

Comment: I think you need to fix your indentation.

Comment: and use proper quotes

Comment: It's pretty obvious from editing your code you haven't actually tried to run it: with basic syntax fixes it works without issues. Without the fixes it fails and gives helpful errors: non-standard strings, wrong indentation

Comment: When do you expect your `while True:` loop to break? It isn't checking the value of `isRealWord`. But, currently, it's a NameError because you didn't capitalise `True`.

Comment: I've replicated your issue and have a solution: once you fix your indentation and syntax issues I'll post and explain how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the indentation/syntax errors are issues with SO and/or lazy copying, as I can replicate your failure example with fixed code:

Everything is compared lowercase except the `vowels` list, which is in all caps. it needs to be `aeiou`, as `A` != `a` and everything else is lowercase.

You still have to fix your syntax, but this solves the question as asked.